# Is there a word for the decoration on top of a building?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word that means "the thingy on top of the building"? Like the crescent on a mosque or the cross on a church or the weather-vane on a barn?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the word ***finial***.

> A distinctive section or ornament at the apex of a roof, canopy, etc. on a building:
>   *curving gables topped by sculptured finials*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/finial)

Comment: Good one, I really didn't know you could use finial to describe the cross or weather-vane.

Comment: Next time you go to a fancy restaurant, look for the finials on top of the lamps.